# Polynomial of degree $4$ has a root of multiplicity $2$ at $x=4$ and roots of multiplicity $1$ at $x=0$ and $x=−4$. It goes through the point $(5,9)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The polynomial of degree $4$, $P(x)$ has a root of multiplicity $2$ at $x=4$ and roots of multiplicity $1$ at $x=0$ and $x=−4$. It goes through the point $(5,9)$.
Find a formula for $P(x)$.

The steps I have taken are:

$$P(x) = (x+4)^2(x)(x-4)$$

$$P(x) = A(x+4)^2(x)(x-4)$$

$$P(5) = A(5+4)^2(5)(5-4)$$

$$P(5) = A(9)^2(5)(-1)$$

$$P(5) = A-405 = 9$$

$$A = 9/-405$$

$$P(x) = -0.02(x+4)^2(x)(x-4)$$

It says the correct answer is $-0.2(x+4)^2(x)(x-4)$

Where have I gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: If the polynomial has a root of multiplicity $2$ and $x=4$ then it has a factor of $(x-4)^2$, but you wrote $(x+4)^2$. Your sign is wrong. Similarly for the single root at $x=-4$ which shows a factor of $x+4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $P$ has a root of multiplicity $2$ at $x=4$ and roots of multiplicity $1$ at $x=0$ and $x=−4$ it follows that $$P(x)=a(x-4)^2x(x+4)\qquad\text{for some constant }a$$ 
Then
\begin{align}
&&P(5)&=9\\
\iff&& a(5-4)^2(5)(5+4)&=9\\
\iff&& a&=\frac{1}{5}
\end{align}
So
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{P(x)=\frac{1}{5}(x-4)^2x(x+4)}}$$